# Maximum number of triangles in a constrained delaunay triangulation

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, upper-bounds, delaunay-triangulation

I'm looking for an upper bound for the number of triangles in a constrained planar delaunay triangulation. I know for d=2 delaunay triangulation, there are at most n+1 triangles where n is the number of vertices.

Is there any papers or theorems that show that constrained delaunay triangulations have fewer or more triangles than normal delaunay triangulations?

http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/pubs/HiDeeDel.pdf

Comment: For 2d the bound you quote is for simple polygon inputs, right? What definition are you using for constrained Delaunay for higher dimensions?

Comment: We're only dealing with 2d for both constrained dt and dt

Comment: But in 2d all triangulations of the same input have the same number of faces. So how could it depend on which type of triangulation you want?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that all triangulations for the same input in 2d have the same number of faces. Us there some theorem that states this?

Comment: Euler's formula: V–E+F=2 for any connected planar map with V vertices, E edges, and F faces.